# Weird output from linux `top` command

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kvm, qemu, top

I got a weird output from command `top`, which shows the summation of the **RES** column is greater than my physical memory. For instance, I have a host with 64G physical memory and the swap partition has been disabled. When I issue the `top` command, and sum up values in the **RES** column for all qemu-kvm processes, I got 72G.

I can't understand, where is the 72G - 64G = 8G memory? How to explain this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resident size (RES) also accounts shared libraries which have been loaded into the process. However, shared libraries are *not* loaded for every single process (they get loaded once and then referenced by the dynamic linker). In fact, the Linux kernel also deduplicates text (binary executable) segments.

If you look in `/proc/$pid/maps` you can see how much memory is 'used' for shared libraries (it's not easy to add, because it's all in hex).